# bash script if statement error

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I am quite new to bash scripting but I managed to write a script that works almost perfectly and I am really proud of myself. However, I have this problem which I dont get why it would not work.
Part of my current code is this:

```
for begin in 1 51
do 
    echo -e "$begin"
    url="http://something&start-index=$begin&something"

    wget -O $HOME/Music/YoutubePlaylist/output$begin.txt $url 2>&1

    cat output1.txt > output.txt

    if ! [[ "$begin" = 1 ]]
        then
        cat output$begin.txt >> output.txt
    fi

done
```

It works perfectly.

However, if I add 101 to the first line, it wont work. 
Any idea why? What it actually does when I look at my temp files, is only write what is in output1.txt in output.txt and nothing else.

PS: output1.txt and output51.txt are not empty whereas output101.txt is empty. Maybe thats an hint....

Comment: please  add "set -x" in the shell script before the for statement. This is the way to debug Shell Script

Comment: Did you try `wget`ting the URL manually for your "101" case?

Answer (score 1):

`cat output1.txt > output.txt` is overwriting `output.txt` for every lap.

Do this instead (only correcting the issue with `output.txt`):

```
rm -f output.txt # if it should start with an empty file

for begin in 1 51
do 
  echo -e "$begin"
  url="http://something&start-index=$begin&something"

  wget -O $HOME/Music/YoutubePlaylist/output$begin.txt $url 2>&1

  cat output$begin.txt >> output.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Such option should work all right:

```
for begin in 1 51 101
do
 echo -e "$begin"
 ...
done
```

Have you checked if `wget -O $HOME/Music/YoutubePlaylist/output$begin.txt $url 2>&1`
exists? Could you execute that from command line and check the result?
e.g.

```
$wget -O $HOME/Music/YoutubePlaylist/output101.txt $url 2>&1
```

Regards